# Turn array from one-line into element-per-line

Tags: text-editing, php-mode

Say I have PHP array like this: `$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];` and I want to convert it to

```
$arr = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
];
```

real quick.

Is there any ready to use soluions?

Comment: Define and use a keyboard macro. Just record your manual edits and replay. Use keys that move syntactically, e.g., search for a comma or whatever.

Comment: @Drew, can I record macro to use it after I close and open emacs again?

Comment: Yes, of course. See the Emacs manual, node [Save Keyboard Macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html). `C-h r` and `C-h i` are your friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about PHP. You can try to search for PHP code formatters and see if it has such function.

Here is a simple solution using regular expression. It works for your particular example at least.

```el
(defun your-php-array-multiline (b e)
  "Turn oneline php array to multiline."
  (interactive "*r")
  (insert
   (replace-regexp-in-string
    (rx (in "[,]"))
    (lambda (s)
      (pcase (match-string 0 s)
        ("[" "[\n")
        ("," ",\n")
        ("]" "\n]")))
    (delete-and-extract-region b e)))
  (indent-region b (point)))
```

In case you want to convert the multiline array back:

```el
(defun your-php-array-oneline (b e)
  "Turn multiline php array to oneline."
  (interactive "*r")
  (insert
   (replace-regexp-in-string
    "\n\s*"
    ""
    (delete-and-extract-region b e))))
```

and toggle between oneline and multiline

```el
(defun your-php-array-toggle (b e)
  "Toggle php array between oneline and multiline."
  (interactive "*r")
  (if (string-match-p "\n" (buffer-substring b e))
      (your-php-array-oneline b e)
    (your-php-array-multiline b e)))
```